# What is the best design for node.js / Express / MongoDB RESTfull APIs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm building some web-services with node.js / Express 3 / Mongoose / MongoDB. I generally see two ways people move code for routes from `server.js` to an external files and I'd like to know what's the main difference, and if one is better than the other? I've outlined the two techniques below. I tend to use method 2 but I find that the `require('./routes/cats')(app, CatModel);` with no `var =` before it just doesn't look right.

1. By Function. Routes are build in-line in server.js but the logic is moved to external files.

Some people seem to do it this way:

// server.js

```
app.get('/cats', cats.findAll);
```

// routes/cats.js

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    // Lookup all the cats in MongoDB / CatModel.
};
```

1. By App. App is passed in and the routes are built on top of it.

// in server.js

```
require('./routes/cats')(app, CatModel);
```

// in routes/cats.js

```
module.exports = function(app, CatModel) {
    app.get('/cats', function (req, res) {
        CatModel.find({}, function (err, docs) {
            if (err || !docs) {
                res.json(kStatusInternalServerError, {error: err});
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.json(kStatusOk, docs);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default way is the first one - and that's why most of us use it.  I prefer to have all of my routes nicely lined up in app.js, with all of whatever's *actually* happening elsewhere.  I haven't seen the second way in production, and I don't see the advantage of tangling routing in with logic.

Comment: Thanks. Would you say its common to add the functionality to find a Cat by ID, name or all cats do the CatModel in mongoose or is this generally done in a `cats` router file?

Comment: @JasonLeach That's outside the scope of this question, fortunately it's pretty easy to ask a new one.  Please upvote and accept if I answered your question!

Comment: I think the second method has the advantage of keeping the route with the logic that handles is. So if you have a path with params in it like `/cats/:cat_id` it is near the code that retrieves the param `req.params.cat_id`. In the first method you need to go to two different places in the code for management. I get that it should not change much but still.